# Website back end users activity log and HIPAA compliance

Tags: database, logging, content-management-system, backend, hipaa

Can someone inform me as to what is the required length of time I should keep website user activity logs in a DB to meet HIPAA compliance?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend asking a lawyer or expert on HIPAA compliance and not trust any legal advice you might get from here:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and I second Josh Berke's comment.

Six months is generally what I've heard discussed as a minimum, but when it comes to HIPAA compliance there is no such thing as being too safe. If there's no technical limitation, retain audit trails for as long as you can.